# I'm getting a strange error?

Tags: php, image

So i'm getting this strange error when I should not be recieving this error? Can anyone help me out here?

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in
>   /home1/hclearne/public_html/database/include/image/16.php on line 9

Code:

```
<?php 
$img = imagecreatefrompng( 'http://i.imgur.com/7MULEJs.png' );
$test = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 255, 0);

imagestring($img, 5, 250, 45, 'UID: $UID', $test );
imagestring($img, 4, 250, 65, 'Rating: $input ', $test );

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng(imagecreatefrompng($img);
imagecolordeallocate($img, 0, 255, 0);
imagecolordeallocate($img, 32, 32, 32);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Comment: Count the brackets on line 9 bro!

Answer (score 2):

It's no strange error, you haven't closed your `imagepng()` function off, you're missing the closing `)`.

```
imagepng(imagecreatefrompng($img));
```

Hence why it says "Unexpected ';'" - Cause it was expecting the closing parenthesis ;-)

Comment: Thanks xD how could I have missed that I literally looked over this code for 10 minutes!

Comment: @CSSWizard Always the ones that hide in plain sight that are the hardest to find ;-)

Comment: That's so true! But thank you again!

Comment: a good IDE would of pointed this out to you saving you 10 minutes you could use to wash the cat, or whatever